# Plugin sub-menu pages recommended structure and links

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu

Sorry if this has been asked before; I have been looking for a while, but couldn't find anything directly applicable. I am building my first plugin and I am trying to follow the [WP best practices](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/best-practices/).

My current plugin structure looks like this:

```
- my-plugin
-- index.php
-- admin (folder
--- sub-menu-page.php
```

I am trying to keep all of my plugin pages separate as part of my organization. However, I can't seem to point my plugin's submenu link to the `sub-menu-page.php` file. Here's my menu code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_pages');
function my_menu_pages(){
    add_menu_page('WISE Admin', 'WISE Admin', 'manage_options', 'wise-menu', 'my_menu_output', 'dashicons-tickets', 2 );
    add_submenu_page('wise-menu', 'General Settings', 'General', 'manage_options', 'general-settings', 'general_settings' );
    add_submenu_page('wise-menu', 'Submenu Page', 'Submenu Page', 'manage_options', 'admin/sub-menu-page' );
    remove_submenu_page('wise-menu', 'wise-menu');
}
```

The submenu link takes me to `/wp-admin/admin/sub-menu-page` which is obviously not where I want to go.

Can I please have some advice for what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're very close.

When you add your first submenu page you want to duplicate your initial menu page. In your second `add_submenu_page` you are missing the function callback for that page. Technically this parameter is optional, but it changes your url from `/wp-admin/sub-menu-page` to `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=sub-menu-page`.

Give this a shot:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_menu_pages' );
function my_menu_pages() {
    add_menu_page( 'WISE Admin', 'WISE Admin', 'manage_options', 'wise-menu', 'my_menu_output', 'dashicons-tickets', 2 );
    add_submenu_page( 'wise-menu', 'General Settings', 'General', 'manage_options', 'wise-menu', 'my_menu_output' );
    add_submenu_page( 'wise-menu', 'Submenu Page', 'Submenu Page', 'manage_options', 'sub-menu-page', 'submenu_settings' );
}
```